# How to diagnose problems with wifi connectivity?

Tags: networking, router, wifi-configuration, mesh-networking

I have a wifi mesh consisting of an AVM 7490 router and 2 AVM 450e repeaters. I often have problems with wifi connectivity in this setup. However devices connected to the router via ethernet cable never have any connectivity problems.

The problems I experience are mainly for devices that are connected via the 2.4 GHz wifi. Android phones either

- show the wifi connection as established, but they do not transmit any data and for example browser connection attempts time out saying that no internet connection is available
- show an exclamation mark next to the wifi symbol
- show an authentication failure when trying to reconnect to the wifi when showing the available wifis
- just abort the connection attempt to the wifi and immediately reattempt to connect to the wifi

At all times the wifi is shown in the list of available wifis. An android phone with 5 GHz wifi does suffer from the problem much fewer times than the android phones with only 2.4 GHz wifi. A FireTV Stick shows the same problems, also the authentication failures. My Lenovo laptop shows the wifi as connected but is unable to connect to websites.

And devices connected to the router via ethernet cable are able to access resources on the internet.

The repeaters are connected to the router with 1 Gb/s Ethernet connections. The router shows the mesh setup as expected. The router doesn't show much activity for the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz frequencies when the problems occur. It lists about 5-8 different wifis on the same channels than mine. The router is configured to automatically pick a channel. It doesn't list any messages related to connectivity problems in its logs.

Only sometimes the problem can be resolved by either restarting the device and/or the router. The problem might disappear some time after it appeared without touching anything. The problems occur throughout the whole day.

What can I do to diagnose the problem?

**EDIT:**
manually configuring the wifi channel didn't solve any problems.

Comment: Have you changed the channel everything is being repeated on? Don't rely on auto channel configuration, it rarely works.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart does this mean the repeaters should use the same or different channels than the router?

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-wifi-authentication-error-occurred-on-android/