# How can I isolate the network connectivity issue on a device?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn

I have looked at this post and it's pretty much describes my problem:
[How to diagnose problems with wifi connectivity?](https://superuser.com/questions/1614737/how-to-diagnose-problems-with-wifi-connectivity)

My problem: A corporate laptop, home office, WiFi connection, losing network connection every hour or so (but not specifically) throughout the day. A phone n WiFi right next to it does not.

How do I isolate the problem on the laptop?
It's a WiFi connection.
There is a corporate VPN involved - does that matter?

MSTeams or MSOutlook will suddenly have a little yellow triangle saying there's a problem, and then I'll find the network is no longer. How do I determine whether it's the VPN that's faulty, or the whole connection?

If I ping the WAP, there's no response, so I'm assuming it's the whole connection that is lost.

Suggestions?

Comment: VPN should not matter.  Update the Wireless NIC driver and the home Router firmware.

Comment: Rightyo, I shall do so.

Comment: A firmware update on the router was due and now done, but the Wireless NIC driver is up to date. I shall monitor behaviour....

Comment: @John It's kinda funny that you just rule out the VPN with no ground.

Comment: No idea why that would be. I have been using commercial VPN for years

Comment: Well, so far it's been behaving beautifully ... my question remains unanswered, but my problem appears solved (touch wood) :)  Thanks very much

Comment: Is laptop connected to 2.4 or 5G?

Comment: 2.4, but 5G is an option I could use. The connection has now been working flawlessly for 48 hours, so that update of router firmware really seems to have done the trick,